# Question probability

Tags: probability

The probability that a man will hit a target is $2/3$. If he shoots at the target until he hits it for the first time, find the probability that it will take him $5$ shots to hit the target.
Please explain the method. Can we use binomial distribution to solve this question?

Comment: Have you thought about this question?

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck? Add that to the question (not in a comment).

Comment: He has to miss the first 4 times, then hit the 5th. You assume all probabilities are independent.

Comment: We ask that you include your thoughts and attempts in every post. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is the geometric probability $\left(\frac13\right)^4\frac23$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for him to hit the shot on the fifth try, he must miss each of the first four times. The probability of a miss is $1-2/3=1/3$. Thus, the probability that he misses the first $4$ times then is successful is:

$$
\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{4}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=\frac{2}{3^{5}}=\frac{2}{243}.
$$